# Validate Uniqueness on belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models:

```
class ServiceType
  has_many :plans
end

class Plan
  belongs_to :service_type
  has_many :agreements
end

class Agreement
  belongs_to :plan
  validates :external_reference, :uniqueness => {:scope => Plan.service_type_id} << this is wrong!
end
```

I need to enforce uniqueness of Agreement.external_reference scoped to the ServiceType. Can't figure out the syntax to implement.

EDIT
I ended up resolving the it like this:

In the end I did:

```
class Agreement
  before_validation :set_service_type

  belongs_to :plan
  validates :external_reference, uniqueness: {scope: :service_type_id}

  private

  def set_service_type
    self.service_type_id = self.plan.service_type_id
  end

end
```

Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: I think You can't implement `scope` on `ServiceType` in `Agreement` as they are not connected.Its like `A->B->C` but you need `C->A`.

Comment: Even though they are connected through B, it's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following fromat

in rails2

```
 validates_uniqueness_of :external_reference, :scope => :your_scope
```

in rails3

```
 validates :external_reference, :uniqueness => {:scope => :your_scope}
```

Comment: Thank you - it's the :your_scope part that I am stuck with.

Comment: That is the filed name with, which you wants scoped it.

Comment: like you want to add a validation on uniqueness on two attributes, that means that your model is valid if the couple of 'external_reference' and 'your_scope(another_field)' is unique.

Comment: I am very new and what you say sounds perfect, I just don't know how to write the code :(

Comment: you wants to validate single field "external_reference" only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom validation.
Let's say, `validates_uniqueness_of_external_reference_on_service_type`

You have to do as follow:

```
class ServiceType
  has_many :plans
  has_many :agreements, through: :plan
end

class Agreement
  belongs_to :plan
  validate :validates_uniqueness_of_external_reference_on_service_type

  def validates_uniqueness_of_external_reference_on_service_type
    errors.add(:external_reference, 'has already been taken on current service type') if plan.service_type.agreements.exists?(external_reference: external_reference)
  end
end
```